# Does conditional rendering of Components Reduces Build Time in Next.JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm building a template in Next.Js that has many possible configurations for styling components, and I have some components that can be rendered or not(it can be configured in the admin page). A simple example would be:

```js
export default function Example(props: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  //...
  return (
    {/* */}
    {isEnabled && <Component />}
    {/* */}
  )
}
```

Where `isEnabled` value is read in `getStaticProps`, at build time. If `isEnabled` is set to `false`, in one or more components, will it reduce build time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So is the idea that you want to have `isEnabled` set to `false` at build time - to reduce the time it takes to build - but change its value to `true` at runtime?

Comment: @juliomalves no. Think of it as a template where a client can configure the look of the application with a settings page, for example. If he disables some components, will it decrease build time?  That's the question.

Comment: Right, got it. I'm not sure it'll have much of an effect in reducing the build time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it will work the way you want, as it still has to be there at read time in order to work. Thankfully, *next.js* supports [dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) which can be requested at the time of use instead. It basically looks like this:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/hello'))

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <DynamicComponent />
      <p>HOME PAGE is here!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Important here is that the `import` statement is inside the `dynamic` function call and the import is not allowed to use any *template strings*.